# net-snmp make fails with configuration options for TLS/DTLS

Tags: openssl, net-snmp, dtls

I downloaded openssl 1.1.0f and net-snmp 5.7.3 on Ubuntu 16.04. Installation of OpenSSL went with no problems. For, net-snmp I ran the `./configure --with-security-modules=tsm --with-transports="DTLSUDP TLSTCP"` and it went well too - the configuration summary showed DTLSUDP and TLSTCP transport support. However, `make` fails with:

```
snmp_openssl.c:167:24: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type "X509_NAME_ENTRY {aka struct X509_name_entry_st}"
```

and

```
snmp_openssl.c:473:37: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type "X509 {aka struct X509_st}"
```

Found many similar errors but can not apply any of that information to my problem. Any ideas?

Comment: It sounds like you are trying to use OpenSSL 1.1.0. Use OpenSSL 1.0.2 instead. File a bug report against *net-snmp*. You can cite the OpenSSL wiki page [OpenSSL 1.1.0 Changes | Compatibility Layer](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/OpenSSL_1.1.0_Changes#Compatibility_Layer).

Comment: @jww must use 1.1.0f

Answer (score 1):

It looks like that version of net-snmp is not compatible with OpenSSL 1.1.0. I suggest you try the latest OpenSSL 1.0.2 instead.